# Svg overlap half a circle

Tags: .net, svg, geometry

I need help with a formula. I have two circles. One is smaller than the other. I know the X, Y and R of the bigger circle, and I know the Y and R of the smaller one.

Now, what I need help with is finding where X of the smaller circles should be when I know how much percentage of it should be overlapped by the bigger circle. For example:

Circle one (biggest one) has: x = 150, y = 250 and r = 150.

Circle two (smaller one) has: y = 250 and r = 80. 45% should be overlapped by the bigger one. what is X for the smaller circle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are at least two values for X (i.e. It could satisfy those by overlapping from the left or from the right). You'd need to define at least one more condition for it to be solvable.

Comment: That's also assuming that it doesn't involve the entire circle and the circle radius is big enough for it to be solvable at all. For example, if the smaller circle's radius was simply 0, it cannot overlap any percentage of the larger circle. Similarly, if the radius was such that the entire circle was exactly the required percentage, X has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: The smaller ones X is always bigger than the bigger ones X, and the smaller ones R is always > 0 and < than the bigger ones R.